# C++ Multiplying 2 ND Matrices

Tags: c++

Tricky question, how to multiply 2 ND metrices? of course columnsA == rowsB...
Here's what i've got:

```
void multiply(int *A, int *B, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i=0;i<(c1*r2);i++) {
         for (int j=0;j<c1;j++) {
             sum += A[(i-i%c1)+j] * B[(i%c1)+j*c1];
         }
         cout << sum << " ";
         sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Calling it:

```
multiply(&A[0][0],&B[0][0],rowsA,columnsA,rowsB,columnsB);
```

Works only for rectangular matrices, obviously. Any suggestion? :)

Comment: There is not a well-defined way to multiply nD matrices (or tensors, as mathematicians/physisists call NxMxLx... tables of numbers). Do you want to multiply each "slice" or what is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I want to multiply 2 nD matrices in the this way: "dot product" of rows and columns.

Comment: @rubenvb: not quite. You probably understand this well, but there *are* specified ways to "multiply" tensors. You just have to distinguish between "row-like" dimensions and "column-like" dimensions, and take care of multiplying "row likes" by "column-likes" (and specify of course which dimensions you want to multiply). This is hinted by Einstein's convention for instance.

Comment: @Alexandre: I know all about that `:)`, it's just not clearly stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a dedicated library for that, such as [Click](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

Or [Click](http://www.ida.liu.se/~pelab/lightmat/)

Comment: Yeah sure, but whats the logic behind it? (Multiplication, not Click)

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion, to make it error-proof, use below technique:

Write a template wrapper such as,

```
template<typename TYPE, size_t ROW_A, size_t COL_A, size_t COL_B>
void multiply (TYPE (&A)[ROW_A][COL_A], TYPE (&B)[COL_A][COL_B])
{
  mulitply(&A[0][0], &B[0],[0], ROW_A, COL_A, COL_B, COL_B);
}
```

There are 2 advantages:

1. You don't have to pass row/column index manually for both arrays in your code
2. Error/bug will be caught at compile time if (Column of A != Row of B)